# Is it possible to have a JAX-RS Service handle GETs and a WebServlet handle POSTs on the same URI?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs

I have a WebServlet handling POSTs via doPost at Path '/rest/foo'

```
@WebServlet("/rest/foo")
```

Is it possible to also have a JAX-RS REST Service handle GET requests to '/rest/foo'?

Comment: The only way would be for your class to implement both the JAX-RS interface and the Servlet interface. I am not sure that's a good idea altogether. Why use the same URL for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in either case the JAX-RS resource or the servlet will intercept the requests. Also, the implementation you propose 'smells'. If you are creating a RESTful API (and considering JAX-RS), it makes a good deal of sense to use JAX-RS, particularly because it supports the REST paradigm quite well. Why not factor out `POST` handling from your current servlet and migrate the logic to JAX-RS. Or stick with the current servlet and expand it to handle both `POST` and `GET`.